# How to handle time unit and step while ingesting or querying in VictoriaMetrics?

Tags: database, curl, time-series, victoriametrics

As a beginner, I tried example-like commands on official docs with a victoria-metrics in docker container.

While I try to write and read to verify whether my operation succeeded, I found it curious: **I can only write with `mil-sec` time unit, while I can only query with `second` time unit**.

How could it be possible that I need to handle different time unit for ingest and query ?
DId I miss any detail about using `step` in a decent way?

Any helo would be sincerely appreciated.

Commands I tried:

```
// try 1: write with mil-sec
// write
curl -d '{"metric":{"__name__":"zoo2","job":"node_exporter"},"values":[0,1,2],"timestamps":[1686207845001,1686207846002,1686207848003]}' -X POST 'http://localhost:8428/api/v1/import'

// no
curl "http://localhost:8428/api/v1/query_range?query=zoo2&start=1686207845000&end=1686207850000&step=1"
// yes
curl "http://localhost:8428/api/v1/query_range?query=zoo2&start=1686207845&end=1686207850&step=1"


// try 2: write with sec
curl -d '{"metric":{"__name__":"zoo3","job":"node_exporter"},"values":[0,1,2],"timestamps":[1686207845,1686207846,1686207848]}' -X POST 'http://localhost:8428/api/v1/import'

// no
curl "http://localhost:8428/api/v1/query_range?query=zoo3&start=1686207845000&end=1686207850000&step=1"
// no, either
curl "http://localhost:8428/api/v1/query_range?query=zoo3&start=1686207845&end=1686207850&step=1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the wrong format for specifying milliseconds - see https://docs.victoriametrics.com/Single-server-VictoriaMetrics.html#timestamp-formats. Try the following:

```
curl "http://localhost:8428/api/v1/query_range?query=zoo2&start=1686207845.000&end=168620785.000&step=1"
```

I've added PR to make units format more clear in docs - https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/pull/4428/files

Update: VictoriaMetrics supports specifying timestamps in milliseconds in `start`, `end` and `time` query args starting from [v1.92.0](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/CHANGELOG.html). For example, the following query is equivalent to the query above starting from `v1.92.0`:

```
curl "http://localhost:8428/api/v1/query_range?query=zoo2&start=1686207845000&end=168620785000&step=1"
```

Comment: Thank you! still confused: does it mean that I should always use a timestamp formated as `1686207845.000` ?  Since I saw write example code (https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#write-data) still uses a timestamp of mil-sec unit.

Comment: VictoriaMetrics mimics Prometheus APIs for ingestion and querying data. And that's how it is defined.

Comment: Hi, I mean if I need to write a timestamp like `1549891472010`, and query with a timestamp like `1549891472.010`, it seems somehow not much straightforward to work with different format timestamp

Comment: @hagen1778, how about allowing to pass Unix timestamps in milliseconds to VictoriaMetrics querying APIs? It shouldn't be hard to automatically detect when the time query arg contains milliseconds instead of seconds by comparing it to big unix timestamp far in the future? For example, if the provided timestamp exceeds `1<<32`, e.g. [2106 year](https://medium.com/@nate510/the-2286-bug-65697bb1b908), then interpret it as milliseconds instead of seconds.

Comment: Agree, opened a FR https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/4459

Comment: FYI, VictoriaMetrics supports timestamps in milliseconds for `start`, `end` and `time` query args of Prometheus querying API starting from [v1.92.0](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/CHANGELOG.html)